# What's the simplest, quickest way to pause/play Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-media-player

I'm just trying to get a quick way to play and pause Windows Media Player remotely. After reading several questions here on SO, I realized that most people were talking about C#, Java, COM, ActiveX... which seem a bit overkill for my project. Is there any simple interface to mess with WMP? My preferred approach would be some Python module where I can just script something up really fast and have it deployed in five minutes. Nothing too fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto

..............

Comment: Just wondering: where is the manual for this? Do I have to dive into the source code to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer, 3 years later, for 64-bit systems:

```
import win32api #needs the pywin32 module
win32api.keybd_event(0xb3, 34) #send the MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE event
```